# Linking two different controls

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sqlite, datagridview

I have shown a part of my Winform application here. The Top most part is the Timeline, The Vertical Lines there indicate the appearance of certain type of messages at those time Instants. Its is linked to the contents of the datagridview which is linked to a SQLite Database

[image]

In normal operation what happens is I load a database. And The database is shown in the datagrid view and then, different type of messages are marked in the Timeline by red/blue/yellow line. The Timeline can be scrolled horizontal by dragging the mouse across.. (i.e It doesnt have an explicit scroll bar)

What I need to do now is that.. If I right click a point on the timeline and click on *Goto LogLine*, The DGV down should automatically scroll down to that line in the DGV that has the same timestamp.

How can this be done??

Comment: Can you based on the location clicked in your Timeline control find the correct timestamp?

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with - finding the right row in the grid, or programatically selecting the row?

Comment: @ba_friend @Charles : I was having a problem getting the correct timestamp from the location of the click and am currently working on it.. But once i do and identify the row in the database , is there a way to highlight that row and show it on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is set the **DataGridView.SelectedCell** to the one of interest, maybe the first cell in the row you have discovered if of interest. Then the DataGridView will automatically being that cell into view by scrolling as needed.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by setting `VerticalScrollingOffset` of the `DataGridView` in the `Scroll` Event using Reflection

include namespace `System.Reflection`

```
PropertyInfo verticalOffset = dataGridView2.GetType().GetProperty("VerticalOffset", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
verticalOffset.SetValue(dataGridView2, dataGridView1.VerticalScrollingOffset, null);
```